# How to past an array of objects to server from android?

Tags: android, arrays, retrofit

I am trying to send an array with a bunch of objects back to android?

I tried String Builder like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for(int i = 0; i <usersChanged.size(); i++) {
            DatabaseUser userChange = usersChanged.get(i);

                if(userChange.getIsFollowingType() == 0) {
                    String userIdStr = "{userId:" +  userChange.getUserId() + ",";
                    String followingStr = "following:" +  String.valueOf(userChange.getIsFollowingType())+ "}]";
                    sb.append(userIdStr).append(followingStr);
```

but I am doing something wrong here. On my server side I am using node.js and would parse the array if I send over a string no problem, but this is not sending a string version of the array? What do I need to change on my string builder? Or is there a more efficient way to send over the list of usersChanged - (which is List)

I am using retrofit if there is a way to do it easy with that.

Comment: Which side you are facing problem?? server Side or android side??

Comment: android side, I am looking for a solution to send over an array

Comment: `StringBuilder`?? use `android.util.JsonWriter` instead

Comment: What is the difference? Efficiency or?

Comment: efficiency, no need for reinventing the wheel and lack of bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will send things like

`[{userId: someuserid, following: someparameter}]`

You need to have the double quote (" ") sent over as well.

```
for(int i = 0; i <usersChanged.size(); i++) {
        DatabaseUser userChange = usersChanged.get(i);

            if(userChange.getIsFollowingType() == 0) {
                String userIdStr = "{\"userId\":\"" +  userChange.getUserId() + "\",";
                String followingStr = "\"following\":\"" +  String.valueOf(userChange.getIsFollowingType())+ "\"}]";
                sb.append(userIdStr).append(followingStr);
```

You should also probably move the "]" to after the loop.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention this, but you can definitely use `JSONArray and JSONObject` to make your life easier.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(...){
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("userId", userChange.getUserId());
    jsonObject.put("following", String.valueOf(userChange.getIsFollowingType()));
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

}
```

Then send over the jsonArray.

Comment: Thanks will try that out now, yeah I have an if else statement just copied it out the code is a lot heavier but that is what I forgot.

Comment: @Lion789 the start with [ is fine, [{"userId":"asdf", "following":"asdf"}] is a valid JSON.

Comment: @Lion789 have updated the answer with other alternative.

Comment: I dont think i can send back a jsonArray with retrofit unfortunately.

Comment: You can try converting that to string first. i.e. `String s = jsonArray.toString();`

Comment: Is there a difference in efficiency ?

Comment: I'm not really sure, mainly it's for convenience